# Google Sheets- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I copied this script from Stackoverflow and changed it a little bit according to my requirements.
It is supposed to send an email to an email address in Column D when the checkbox is checked in Column I.

But it is giving this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')"
Here is my sample [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO4yIJsBJzzTxjauqFaF1zlCPMcPWK0yEl7KJvXzssQ/edit?usp=sharing)

`

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;

  Logger.log(cell.getColumn());
  Logger.log(cell.isChecked());
  //Check if the checkbox in column I(index 9) was checked
  if(sheet.getName() == "Sheet2" && cell.getColumn() == 9 && cell.isChecked()){

    //get current row values from column A to column G
    var values = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,7).getDisplayValues().flat();
    Logger.log(values);
    var email = values[4];

    
    var message = "Your application is Approved";

    //Send email
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Your Application Status ",
      htmlBody: message
    });

    
  }
}
```

`

I tried a script from Stackoverflow but It gave error.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Answer (score 1):

Do not run the code directly in the script editor. If you do, the event parameter `e` is not populated, causing the error you mention.

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that is designed to run automatically when you *manually edit* the spreadsheet. In that context, the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e` is properly populated.

Simple triggers run in a restricted context where the identity of the user at the keyboard is usually not available. *"They may or may not be able to determine the identity of the current user, depending on a complex set of security restrictions."* See [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) and [Session.getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser).

Further, you cannot send email from a simple trigger. Use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead. See your script project's [execution log](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1NtUj7NRz6T48HNZDFDYrOvUpEjvYb34UNYnwmrA5hWnVZpojPxH5-D1l/executions) to see the errors your script is producing.

Comment: Sir I have added an OnEdit Trigger but it is not sending emails, can you please look into script?

Comment: You cannot send email from a simple trigger. Edited the answer per your new requirements.

Comment: Sir can you help me to configure this? I am new to apps script and could not solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/13045193)